# Want to control when cache is written with Apollo client

Tags: javascript, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have an issue that writing apollo_client cache to browser storage is consuming a lot of time.

Is there any option, with which I can control when the cache is written to browser storage?

Eg I'd like to do a bunch of micro requests and once all data is returned, I write the latest state of cache only once to the browser storage?

Comment: Apollo Client by itself doesn't write anything into browser storage. If you use additional libraries, please state those libraries, their versions, and show the code you use to initialize all that. Without that information, it's impossible to give any feedback.